# How to add a print statement in a complicated expression?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
prime_numbers = [
    number
    for number in range(2, 101) 
    if all(number % div != 0 for div in range(2, int(number**0.5) + 1))
]
```

How would I add a print statement for number?

Comment: Python hasn't had a "print statement" [since 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) - it's just a function call, you can put it anywhere any expression would go. Or use a debugger.

Comment: This is already difficult to read - don't write such complicated expressions. Flatten it out into explicit loops.

Comment: great comments, but is it possible to do ?

Comment: You can use it, but it will almost certainly mess up the rest of the code, because `print()` reutrns `None` and you won't be able to use the value being printed.

Comment: E.g. if you write `[print(number) for ...]` you'll get a list of `None` values, not the numbers.

Comment: But as it's just a function returning None, `print(number) or number` is... `number`. It's unclear what you're actually stuck on once you know it's _not_ a statement.

Comment: I assume you don't want to see the numbers from 2 to 100, so why isn't adding `print(prime_numbers)` as the next step the right solution?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I believe it is a statement. It runs in spyder just without output.  I n=believe the student got this from the internet.  It's not the way I would have done it but trying to provide a complete answer.

Comment: ...what student?! You can believe that all you like, but it's simply not true in Python 3.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What's not true - it doesn't run in spyder? It does!

Comment: _"I believe [print] is a statement"_ - _that's_ a statement, and it's an incorrect belief.

Comment: @Barmar exactly where in the statement would you add [print(number) for ... in the statement. since I just want to print out the numbers why would I get none? I don't really care about what print is returning

Comment: You would change `[number` to `[print(number)`. But like I said, it won't work because then you're making a list of the return values of `print()`, which is `None`.

Comment: @Barmar  I can't believe it.  I finally stumped Barmar!  It does work and it prints the numbers we are looking for not none!!!  Although prime_numbers is a list of None's

Comment: For pity's sake; that's _exactly what they were telling you_ would happen (and what the docs and other basic research would also indicate). `print(number)` prints the number **and returns `None`**. If you didn't actually want the list of numbers you shouldn't have been writing a list comprehension to begin with.

Comment: @DCR That was my point. It breaks the part that's supposed to fill in `prime_numbers` with a list of prime numbers.

Comment: @Barmar too much to hope that I stumped you.  Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically since the truthiness of `print(number)` is `False` (`print()` returning `None`), you can enjoy it's effect and use an `or` to get the result in the list still.

```
prime_numbers = [
    print(number) or number
    for number
    in range(2, 101)
    if all(
        number % div != 0
        for div
        in range(2, int(number**0.5) + 1)
    )
]
print(prime_numbers)
```

Giving you:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

However, comprehensions are discouraged for side effects like this (at least by me). You might want to just use a more traditional `for` loop.

See also: [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects#:%7E:text=Using%20a%20list%20comprehension%20for,which%20side%2Deffects%20are%20important.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
def my_print (thing):
    print(str(thing))
    return thing

prime_numbers = [my_print(number) for number in range(2, 101) if all(number % div != 0 for div in range(2, int(number**0.5) + 1))]
```

But I agree with others who say that the expression should be broken out. That makes it more readable. And can also allow you to use a more efficient algorithm for listing primes than trial division.

Comment: Why call `str`?